# Splunk - Add numeric columns and display only that result

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-dashboard

This is my Splunk query:

```
| stats count by Successful_Unsuccessful
```

This is what the result looks like: [image]

What I want to do is total all the numeric values in the count column and display it as a Single Value Visualization in a dashboard panel

I tried doing this which sort of works but doesn't fulfill my requirement:

```
| stats count by Successful_Unsuccessful 
| addcoltotals labelfield=Successful_Unsuccessful label="Grand Totals" count
```

This does add all the numeric values and gives me the total but I want the Grand Total to be the only value that appears so that I can use it in a Single Value Visualization in a Dashboard Panel

Issue in picture: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single-value visualization, all you need is the total count.

```
| stats count
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. You are a legend. Thank you